# Run 'on-demand' git server over EC2/Google Cloud Platform

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I would like to run a git server on which I can back up my projects. At most I would need the server to be running 1 hour a day. I was now curious if it is somehow possible to run a git server on EC2 or Google's equivalent, which only 'spins up' -- similar to Heroku -- whenever I try to access the server over SSH, and shuts itself down an hour or so later?

I have only dealt with dedicated/virtual Linux servers thus far, so I am a bit clueless as to the more flexible solutions out there.

Comment: Heroku is a PaaS, whereas EC2 is an IaaS, so any kind of behaviour like you describe would have to be implemented from scratch yourself. Someone else may have already done that, though I'm not aware of anything. Is there a reason why you don't want to use Github or BitBucket?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Really only a question of price. I'd also like to have the ability of saving snapshots, and having large repositories.

Comment: You can't start anything up when you SSH into the instance, you need something up to listen to the connection. You can however use the AWS API to write a script that will quickly start or stop an instance when you need it.